# Python code ignoring if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

In the process of writing an app, I've come across a bizarre python code piece that I can't understand:

The Code:

```
msg = [108878, [[314.06, 2, 4.744018], [314.03, 1, 15.9059], [314.02, 2, 79.8338531], [314, 1, 54.90047253], [313.56, 2, 1.75392219], [313.53, 2, 15.61132219], [313.5, 1, 0.554316], [313.42, 1, 1.5976], [313.27, 1, 0.43344], [313.26, 1, 62.724], [313.25, 1, 2.57518855], [313.24, 1, 0.04], [313.09, 2, 22.51784808], [312.9, 1, 40], [312.82, 1, 26.65592034], [312.7, 1, 35.53791008], [312.62, 1, 0.46912], [312.61, 1, 100], [312.6, 1, 48.33502123], [312.57, 1, 4.24547326], [312.56, 2, 0.2], [312.5, 2, 109.76863639], [312.43, 1, 100], [312.42, 1, 0.11142352], [312.4, 1, 7.815571], [314.09, 2, -3.01187461], [314.14, 1, -1.27056771], [314.39, 2, -9.31898324], [314.46, 1, -0.01930229], [314.49, 1, -0.40344], [314.5, 1, -3.40637161], [314.53, 1, -0.2], [314.54, 2, -0.46432889], [314.57, 1, -0.04200538], [314.71, 1, -0.050949], [314.84, 1, -0.02153813], [314.88, 1, -0.04200538], [314.93, 1, -68.439], [314.94, 2, -7.477782], [314.95, 1, -5], [315.1, 1, -5.97], [315.12, 1, -0.01], [315.16, 1, -40], [315.2, 1, -0.04200538], [315.22, 1, -25.7525], [315.23, 1, -78.54523718], [315.38, 1, -80], [315.42, 1, -6.65060488], [315.47, 1, -20], [315.48, 1, -5.36]]]

bids = asks = {}
lenbids = lenasks = 0
for order in msg[1]:
    if float(order[2])>0:
        lenbids +=1
        bids[order[0]]=order[2]
    elif float(order[2])<0:
        lenasks+=1
        asks[order[0]]=-order[2]

print(len(bids),len(asks),lenbids,lenasks)
```

Output:

```
50 50 25 25
```

It seems to me as though python is behaving properly with regards to the lenbids/lenasks actions but is executing the second part of the if statement regardless of whether the condition is met or not?

I'm running Pycharm with Anaconda3 if that makes any difference.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If statements work fine... The dictionaries are the exact same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `bids` and `asks` to be the **same** dictionary:

```
bids = asks = {}
```

You want them to be **different** dictionaries

```
bids, asks = {}, {}
```

Comment: Thanks donkopotamus! I often do things like a=b=0 to initialise variables and never had any issues with that....didn't know you couldn't do that with objects

Comment: *Everything* in Python is an object, including integers. But integers are not *mutable* objects (modifiable in-place), while dictionaries are.